# Insert a symbol include first and last position

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Assume we have a list

```
list = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
```

Then use this code:

```
StringRiffle[list,"*"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

But `"*a*b*c*d*e*f*"` is expected.So we should

```
"*" <> StringRiffle[list,"*"] <> "*"
```

Have a terse method do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`StringRiffle` can also take strings to prepend and append to the result if you supply three delimiters instead of one. It's not *that* much terser though:

```
StringRiffle[list, {"*", "*", "*"}]
```

Of course you could remove the duplication of the strings with

```
StringRiffle[list, ConstantArray["*", 3]]
```

if you like.

For the sake of completeness, the order of the three strings in the list is `{prefix, infix, suffix}`, e.g.

```
StringRiffle[list, {"<", "*", ">"}]
(* "<a*b*c*d*e*f>" *)
```

---

Alternatively, if you always want to insert some string before/after every *character* (that is, if the strings in `list` will never contain two or more characters), you can also use `StringReplace`:

```
StringReplace["abcdef", "" -> "*"]
(* "*a*b*c*d*e*f*" *)
```

Comment: Very good solution.Cost my some time to research...

Comment: A workaround come to my mind.`StringReplace[StringJoin@list,RegularExpression["\\B|\\b"]->"*"]`

Comment: @yode you can have that more easily with `StringReplace["adefgh12c34", "" -> "*"]` but of course a lot less flexible since `StringRiffle`'s first list may contain strings that are longer than a single character. I'll add this though if it's useful to you.

Comment: You  help me once again..